# Parsing YAML in Scala/Circe into case classes with union types

Tags: json, scala, parsing, yaml, circe

I have a YAML file that contains 3 types of fields defined in the example below. Essentially I want to be able to parse this into generic case classes that represent those data models.

This YAML file will change very often, including field names, values, etc. The only thing that won't change is the high level format of each data type (seen below)

The biggest problem is how can you define a case class that accepts multiple types into the same field and parse the YAML into them?

Most of the examples online don't seem to have a lot on this subject, so I tried a couple different things that ultimately came up short. It looks like there's a problem with using sum types like Either with the circe library as I get the below error. I also tried using a `sealed trait` and union types to no avail.

Example YAML File:

```
name: ExampleYamlMapping
version: 0.0
mappings:

  # Single Value Field
  - name: fieldtype1
    value: "singlevalue"

  # Multivalue Fields, Unformatted
  - name: fieldtype2
    value:
      - "multivalue"
      - "multivalue1"

  # Formatted Multivalue field
  - name: fieldtype3
    content_type: "formatted multivalue"
    format: "key1 | key2"
    mappings:
      - name: key1 # Single Value Field
        value: "singlevalue"

      - name: key2 # Multivalue Field, Unformatted
        value:
          - "multivalue1"
          - "multivalue2"
```

Example Case Classes:

```scala
case class UnorderedField(name: String, value: Either[String, List[String]])

case class OrderedMultiValueField(content_type: String,
                                  format: String,
                                  mappings: List[Either[UnorderedField, OrderedMultiValueField]])

case class ContentMappingExample(
                           name: String,
                           version: String,
                           mappings: List[Either[UnorderedField, OrderedMultiValueField]]
                           )
```

Parsing Logic:

```scala
import io.circe.generic.auto._
import io.circe.{Error, Json, ParsingFailure, yaml}

val mappingSource = scala.io.Source.fromFile(mappingFilePath)

mappingData = try mappingSource.mkString finally mappingSource.close()

val mappings: Either[ParsingFailure, Json] = yaml.parser.parse(mappingData)

val contentMapping: ContentMappingExample = mappings
      .leftMap(err => err: Error)
      .flatMap(_.as[ContentMappingExample])
      .valueOr(throw _)
```

Error Message is:

```
CNil: DownArray,DownField(mappings)
DecodingFailure(CNil, List(DownArray, DownField(mappings)))
```

Answer (score 3):

Update on this: I figured out that you can create Algebraic Data Types (ADTs) and define custom encoders in circe. I followed the following example which works for me: https://circe.github.io/circe/codecs/adt.html